# How to save base64 string as an image to local server in django python

Tags: python, django, image

I have base64 string and I try to encode it and then save it in a folder. So far I have been doing this

```
data = {"status":"Trial"}
if request.method == 'POST':
        decoded = request.body.decode("UTF-8")
        userdata = json.loads(decoded)
        image = base64.b64decode(str(userdata))
        print(type(image))

        save_path = "Dummy/test"
        if not os.path.exists(save_path):
            pathlib.Path(save_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            img_save_path = "%s/%s%s" % (save_path, str(uuid.uuid4()), ".jpeg")
            with open(img_save_path, "wb+") as f:
                for chunk in image.chunks():
                    f.write(chunk)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

when I try the above code, the image is saved inside `Dummy/test` directory but when I open the image.. it says that the image can not be opened and here is the error log

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'chunks'
```

Is there a right way to save base64 string as an Image in django python?

Second code edit after doing trial here is what I do:

```
data = {"status":"Trial"}
if request.method == 'POST':
        decoded = request.body.decode("UTF-8")
        userdata = json.loads(decoded)
        image = base64.b64decode(str(userdata))
        print(type(image))

        save_path = "Dummy/test"
        if not os.path.exists(save_path):
            pathlib.Path(save_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            img_save_path = "%s/%s%s" % (save_path, str(uuid.uuid4()), ".jpeg")
            with open(img_save_path, "wb+") as f:
                f.write(image)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `f.chunks()`?

Comment: @jackl, the right way to save the image after doing ```with open(img_save_path, "wb+") as f:```

Comment: Oh right. Can you show what you are doing when you try to open it?

Comment: @jackl, when I open it, the pop message shows with a message like this: ```The file “7ad4440c-7de5-46d7-b01c-d838a3274f05.jpeg” could not be opened because it is empty.```

Comment: Maybe the file isn't being written to if `os.path.exists(save_path)` is true.

Comment: @jackl I have edited my question and delete the ```chunk``` and able to open and save the image now, I just want to ask.. so the second code that I have posted is right way to do it right ?

Answer (score 0):

**Why not to use an easy method for achieving this:**

```
file = request.data.get('image')
format, imgstr = file.split(';base64,')
                        ext = format.split('/')[-1]
                        image_file = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr), name='temp.' + ext)
```

**Format of your base64 will be** `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBYVFRgWFhYYGRgZHBwaGhwaGhwcHhocHBoaGhkaHBocIS4lHB4rHxwYJjgnKy8xNTU1GiQ7QDs0Py40NTEBDAwMEA8QHxISHzQrJCU0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NP/AABEIAPsAyQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAADAAMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQYCAwcBAAj/xAA9EAACAQIFAgQDBgQFBAMBAAABAhEAAwQFEiExQVEGImFxE4GRFDJCobHwB1LB0RUjYnLhM4KS8RY0UyT/xAAZAQADAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEAAX/xAAnEQACAgICAQQCAgMAAAAAAAAAAQIRAyESMUETIlFhBKEygRRxsf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AbpZ1LW/A2iGrdgLQiKMWxpNRUZLZ0H4YagIoomUNa7O4ra6wp9q0RehZLZx/xakYlvalYWKa+Lj/AP0n2/rSphNRl2GPQ88JH/PHtXWkTUgFcf8ADAi+DXWrF+AKpj6Fl2KsTljawRxO/rTyzdFtRNbQ4Imp/O7jtsgovWxX7UU+HxauJBqc8T2FdSK14G46JvSjGZiS+kms+SbapISUm1SIHE2DZviNgTVXh2ZkkHegPEWDLLqX3mjPCeHuXVAIhfXrU8sW40+xlFtDTBPA3PzrHNMUoWJqgt5AI5rXe8KI3NZ4/jb2hVim2c+sobjMR0pZisIwfcHf0rrOG8PoggKKyfIkJkgVRYnZX0WczsoVAMH6VpxN5jtpb6GurrkyD8I+lenJ7f8AKPpQWBXbAsD+TkWGwrN+E/SnuX4V04VvmK6LYytBwB9KKTBKO30ppYeSoHofZzfEYhl+8pFfWcV1rol7KUbkCgB4aQncCs7/ABHH+IJYJeGTNm/Nb9XrVTZ8O21/DRH+CW/5RSf4EmL6MiWtKUeKZO0ii8wy/qKn8RfKSN9q9ZTi9FrocYW/vFM8Q3kPtUhhMUxMijsRjH0EGRtRWSKRzOceJ21YlvSKE01njyTeae9eD7wHcgfXapydjpaHWRolofab76EB0ov4rh6xOwUdWNZnxbisUxTDINIJUsBrjqCW4+napLxdi2uYn4UxbtAW0A38qcn1JMmqTwp4rsYUaAmkH7x5kid/bj6VSKqNnPsv8gxeICItzD3NlAd2Klp/EdCmYmY6xFP1toYPNRL/AMTrat5UY/l035+VGZT47tYi6FYaNUgE8bbiTxJFMmK0U+OVQhrn+KQtegHarXNMSuk+YcdTt1/tU8li0JdnWZ7jaeKhkyxiVhhcvBvTCKygESKdZXghbUACldrEpq0hxqiYO0+0+xozLc6RwTEAEiSRyCQQPpzSL8iMuxvQlEoLfFfNcoS3j0bYHevXeqck1aEprTMw+9elqD+LG54FZvjLaJrd1A9x+tBKwtmGZZollRqI1MwVFJjUx4HXb1iibbSK4P41zQnHu63C6r/0zyAscD5zv6127w8rHDWmbkoJ94jrTSjVAjKwuyxmiFNYKtbFpUEzZtqwtsa+ucVhZej5OCdRr6TWJevNdMA0YgyKlcxwhJNVOsGhrtkGoJpkbJ7J8CVPmpnj7Q0RRy2wK04q35TSySsKZx3M7em8/vQ1tyHQiCQw2PB34O/FMPElvTePrSp0qi6KLoN8bZWfio6+UnUYMQJ3ieKnfsLny7cdDz0FdGeL6INGtNPmmTG0GZO9E2fC9m0VuKXIiSjDaO89AKRZ+Kpl3i5O0Q+C8MXCfORG0gckHqnT5HvFWuXeD0ChtKgngupZt+Giem3ptRec5ktoQuHYnbTpBI99hxt1pPYzTG3ZW2jxMPogHfprOygfM+lSnlyTWtDxxxj2FZpl+FtQcTiLrk7BdZkxPCLvwYitVjMcJMLgbhXnV8BmPTuCf2KxxltMPGu/hrDmJKg3rzE93eD84PNBZfni/EIGIxTzJJ020SN+kc8VNJtXbf6X/ClpOtBl7G2ijkWXtSpDa7LppnqHQEDp04ofJ7uFYJpa8biLBNtDcUNzq2BXmela878V3bYX/IuBW4a5BkTwoX070JhPGiqsW0Aht1VYZtRJLL0jjmOfSio5KtL9hco3Tf6KZMWWbRaxdovBKpetaGJO4IKxJ9Ip9l2NxKMEv2QwI2e2wZRH8waCOnE81MWrz4pAwW1ilnzWnAS7bP8ApaYn6e9F5XnItN8EO6NO1jFbOB2t3ZIbrsSfcVynNdd+UI4xfYj8f57iVusk6LY4CTJ6eb+boekevNQt/GX7g+8xUCBJOwmY+p/OuneJbCuw0CLjDVoIl/WAOeOR2qQTA3Un/LKIYBLKRJG09+/1PetWL8hOO+yM8LvXQoyPKHu3hqAgFeeswYHy/pX6KwxC20TsBXPPCuBVigB1aSCTETIAn6bRV7jb0GO3t/eujkc5N+FoEoKMUgw8Vil3egbeK71vUzTKSfRNOw03Aa8ShCY61j9oiusNBrtFCfaxQubZiEQknpUF/wDLV701i2XQxcda8u48RS+/h/Wh3sMRArzE+OrIppDKzmIJ5r3EY8d6SJhGWtj4NmFOn9nJoi/FF0NdBFLtNE+IcOUufOg1aK2x/ii0XosfCF93b4bIpVVnzSdjxsdiKs3ZVRi+hP5QwDEj1n14HSp3JsV9mwmp5kDVv68KB+fzqHxucXsfd0WgQG6zAAFQatul/ZqiqSseP4kZ7xVtFxmMW7YYhedtXRuSf/W7fDvjGXQz2wXkeQMAincxO5eOpqAwd5Uxlu3YQFlYI7PuWPBjsBPNdgy3Cp94Elh3H73/ALV0oStJLs5SjTbOd47w/Zwph71kXH/HeJZp52SIX3Pel+HwlppH+IWgJ4VPYwD2/sKos/8A4ZPeuNcW95mJJ1KTMknn0mPYCpu34EFt9N3EoCDsBG/yJnvVZRUVcmTjJyftX7Guc2LVnDrbZ2vF2UrraS24I0H8AA7UT4ftYa/Ya2nkOrzQRqUgjYnqKQZ74fe3cF5r4YCQoPOrSwVFEwBx9DQuXYB1xELdFs3Bq0sGhw6yyhhsYaY9j88/FShqW+7L8mntfRnicsvYVzrFxADqS+gJQbmNUbHpt77VXZHmCYtTZxyI+xa1dGyuOpR/wsB0majcVi8ww10WBeLzGlSQ4M8KwPJroPhHDHEWXW/hfg3VIYjQVR9o1AHYHcg1WcW4KWn9okpJSa6+mEXszXBoNLB0DBAHlniJ3uLO3qR715meCbE2luIHRWEyCrHjrp6Ug8QZXcS4qYZl0uGJsux351BZPX97cOfAWZ20Bs+ZGJM2zwhP4VHT8xUeCklIpycXSMvDlgYMM1xhqPG0T1kLNNb+dLcIMjbtxR+dZSHXVBb11Hb10jY0mXJQBV4x4ozZJNuw84kRIIrbgscp60jvYRxsKR4t7ts9aWMvcRjLZe4vFqOtAWMwVmiaiWxV1yBqIFbsFhLgfyt13qpVsM/iDjytuFPO1cu+LVx42tvplpio7y1RPQkns741ma2Jh45pwMOK+a0Kh6C7E9NCRsNPSvPsp7U7FoCvigorDEKxo5J44sFHBI60r8OYT4+IRIJUGWjsKpP4lMIVepaiPA2VvaRrr6ePKdpURvud/wAqfjSpFIpLQt/iTmy2LQsofOw+g6+xpT4SVLBRGJDsoedgN+nO/wCVasPkr5jib1645CI8Ag8wfuiR+dAZtdNzH6bIbShRAV/CEAmY2Fc8a41/ZRTfKwyzhFtZmp1CHDOQYhdUkGeI6/Oug3/ElpLBbD3bb3HIS2uoAa24LHoB29I5rnFnMraY9r13/oQbJYiQTpKk7dOQacDL8qZ1cOir+HRcgE7fhPmXcd4mnhHpv4Em6tL5H3+HY9GtNcxZuP8AERtCSqldUMpjYKBJ9eOk1v8AE+UW8OWu20FzFXSYLbnfYkbbBZ/KhcvzYnEorvqXQCr9H0z8gwlT6yaQ51ndx8xdtY+GiqqgdSQW0g9N9z/tWkyPkmPjVNCwWMTc8+LcaCWOmIOobbAdBQ2NxN62zLpLaG+LaMahpWAQ3oAS0+tFYfAs6urXWd0tKCSfKHL6mQesBZ67+tbMrV1vIweZD/e/kbSSD3hyPlNRtW+v9dFqdeSufwlh8wsC83+XeKg6h0221DtVp4XwDYfDpba6bxEgPzIO43k7DioX+HFz4lzEFy5AXQg/CEDNqX1KtIntpp05xD4RreHY2m1t59tlXYqvYkj5VoxKoqJnyO5OQq/ixlzrbS9a1BkaWKzOnfqN4mKVZPhruNwwxKkribRK6+PiARsQB8q3Ytsyv4a6mJRFtok62ddRZNxsI1A9ZAo4eIhYy21cRAjXVAUIBCseSB22P1qWSLWkvOh4S8v4Knwlm7Yi2yXF03EGllP74rVduFSRuI6Usw+YLax1hiY+PZXUOs9Gjrvt86YeI9SvPKsAQRxQuUY7I52ltHtsy29a80y5XHyoXD4r60Rdxmkb1PnXghCViazke49DTrC4MJu0UquZ4qUizfxMzbLtVYpsvRs/iDikddCnc8VDf4c/f8qcvbL+cySN5Nffa27Ci8laIzls7u1+sfi1qYgc0O2IEwDTOdFnoMa7WL3djQZvgdawv4gFTFBzpWIp30cx8cYotiUE8H33mrWGTB6Ro1FN4ECSOw6/OpgYMXceoZZjzbkxA7jSR9Ypr4zxZRAFZgNvu7D6jehFtpFIdWxPkxNjCuE++NbRH4t+h5oPwfaCYX4jffuF3ZhzBJ7dflSXEeJXtBiulgIVl4gkSD1nsaIbGBstZ7ezJtsQSoLBoI7TI+VM1Jqn5Y8ZJOwH46LiyrgHDvCqY8qbQpI4G/60DewCYe9ds3DoV90eNtP7Na7lw6VuAKyusOOT22XimGGxXxVXD311oD5XPldPZt5FMnqmdJbtGWRZwlm4tktrtnYNts57dga0+ILejENDHYagf9wH5wKSZ9lv2e8yKSRAZSSJg+1F4rGNfbV10qP/ABFdKK00dGT6KnLsxm0ANiJ2AHmniT+KhLmLKl2UmSGA6kEkEEexBrXlGHlCCOIn05/5/wCKJxWC3BAPffpE9etZeKTZp5NpDjwvijYtX8S8pbJZm6S0Q2kdyQPmaXLn+LLeQ/Dsqh08Ed5YnknmaXZ9mgfDWcMp+41x7nTg+Qe8sfmBWzD+GbqIrYy6bWHMEKGLlhyFAHFa4R9tmWUvdTGNjMcfiMCXu3UXDliGIXS7BegAOnSSN9p3o/Mcu1ZVaYMXW26ujbglH2GoTuyklflSTNs2W81qwlvRYHltpJACxDO0bFiOB+e9WGTYpcRl+KRVCW7SNaQ9CVUeaI/mpJNymq6Q0UlF35F3je6LOLwRBjQideBIG4HsOO1dOxttbtgPPAmfvfpXLf4h5PdFzD3olES2jR0g7n23FdTyhw2HTSJEcf03qsopqiN32QuJxGlth+RH6gUrx2bdJp5nWFCXiSpUE9e5rXb8Po4k1limnQkVTaRLXbRcSDSlrTF4j3qk8QWTh1OkSKl8sxmt9wQJ4p03s5zexricQiJpPPpSj469monOLE/dn5Uq+w3expaXlkdHfsSJHNTd7FFH2NHY66zISrdKicZmLq0RqPpWfNuVobLNPof4nGMeDFZYTEuoJdpqSuZg/UfKvGx1xxpAP6UIpy3IlGyjyq+XvOyAEtCbz77bbmm3iTDh1Cam9ljfufQVN5HNqCSAWJPX2ljJ236darSFddiNxv69960x+D0Yr2o4/i0VMQ9hwdD7Dcc/zcbmmeWYQ4bUyS9r7t5G3Ok/iG28fpNG+K8kV3NwGNIJkc+gHzrRkeKkIyOC0aLgMbjvtx/zVW9AS2Jcww6WrjLbtsEbzKwJKsD2beNv0rLDoDxsBzO0fXmmOKwbWnfD6/h2m/zUcRt0KSdomlweFHn1DcBogt0Hy9aWRSL8AOZLrck8gR9OBROBwTFdQQkdZHr06V89uUJEA8njqdon1pvkzudIAO0frzO35GuttUGkmOcnykAhuQw3g8b8HeOvIoy9gwPLHWBtxPrPP75r6w+iC0iNiQJ7Rx6Hmi1xBZdSrsN5UBTAMgAbcdanJDpkldyVNTFiRGknoY1cien9qos/U4hF1nyrBWII2E8d/wDmtVwK5dNgI2AJMFeQdomDzt1ozKcSGQo6nUNgQQD3AE8nnvSPJLUbG4R3KiUXCraZ2NsyEDao8h5jfpHy+dUvhbEscus2/utiLpJHllk16nIE8bEcdaFS38R3wouXEdlV9dxAQUJ3TSCIME89ZpP4uN69iERQqJa8moNCqBBk8BTA7T71qgqW/JlyO3rwdU8SWBdtad5GkyOY60TkNgogBYgEDSC07Dpv1ipTBZqmIQJaaSgCTqEmBzB3g8T61TfEU21RzpaBsYXcdjxPpO/Q0W9ieBV4mzMklUvqVnQ1t5DTE7Nyp9GifWQKT2c4NoaXBB9ams5u31um3cfWEYhGkE6Z+63X67z32hLmGLP3RyaRyuRJSplfmmbJdXekti5bEkRNA4ZW0RMmlvxCjEEc0sabaApJsaPjFD800+2r2FSTGWBo/wCIaZxic0izbxFK6AwJ70CoG7nk705veFURJX60ouWmUaflWaSfOicYcmCWret5jb1poiKnMURgMuESTFE4zJw4kNRa2O6joRZ3dC6HEHp7ev8AzRmGzvhAJ277cc+379hfEOH0WVnfzR+RpLgiTsX0+kST2AGk0IPRtxU4IpswvI7BCCzOD92f7/pHHpUPmmT4jC3C9tW7+VTp9tulW+CQbHWg9F2j3HLH5V5mVtWB85knykid/qPetMJAlEl8PffGKNQ1aILJwQwkqZnZT1mg71tgTrK6zyBwPQHrFG4fC4hHe4hDeXTJnUxJ6Ejid9zFK7OJcM7tpYzAVukMd47UZL4Oi/kzxF0uiqQdOoDaJg8n17/KqPKnIKLqEgHtJj73z4PXipPHYgvLEEadz7bCQOlMsLjEkMqO5XaRwvr9D070FHQW9ljiCViZE8j720iYgiaa5eyqNyASPL0MyDz9PoKnFzFLiTrAImZ2PTkH3I571nhczU+V3gDk7Q0HoO3H50nGx+VBV1VW8dJ0nsSAOgI26c/MUQuEDkELJngHSDBBUL0DSNjzPvQqYy090gNrRQAW0952PoN/rx3ZHMVRdSI7oGSYBICsJ1Bpk6d54qMoS56LKUeJjm+boiaPKl1WGm5MBlcElhO4I4Kng+1Q+b5cbkJbB1BpMb6xyW59zv2NV/ijCvisThiif5NtdTXJEksd/KBMCBued6p7GRp98qFdeDqG0e3ffn+la2+NMxrdoXeDsgS1aViNyJOoQQR+h9ev0ph4nJABXaQAVMETvvvM9f2aNsXQ+oBpXTvt1HqOaTeLJIWCQIG3yqEsnIGWHGDInE2izH9+wrRh8tZiWIFG3PKa34fFKBvse9KpUtGFy0C3csZBMbelJceA0QPnVTczEOpHypauXFiWjamjIVMm0wrkgCjPsL9qbpZaYC8Ud9kfsaPJB5De5mLgBWrTGs0w+xq7TRP2UJSKPu5GyEK2hFj1uqPKYoBMwvqN5iqV0LHcbUFm7oqQBv2p1jQmSKsTZ9jQ9lAedUyOmxpBZdgYTnue3UH0phjGAQEmIn9IpVbc7gCIqclWjZhjxgkN8rxUnSFWfYn6AmIpvcQusME094HP0pLl+CAi7ccIn8xIJY/6VG+3X9iqO2RtpnSQNzAJnedRkxBHAFMtbGlsUPiWSbbKxTeHHG0ERJ8xHO3ap+4LeIBLtpuqyrrH4+0gcSatcTglcTw3RoloAnZnkye5ipm9lFoudSvrkw1sydjO6mJI3mJ9qqmSAcDh3RmR01hxo1KNQ5IIbtFL8YLmFaANVo/hPQHpPI52qhwGVujBkvIw8zBbhdCW/wBUc/SmOa4XVbK3kDSdijAkzGwBjjpHQUykl2dvtEpZwSlAytJaCpYARqg7knzR6H5TWjAYi810ogRjOkvokKACPLx0J5pn/hLi+iNp+GoLKCJIEg7L/NJ2+dUeT20RB8C07QZ1NoE6pnrI9/b1puVd7A/rQLbsph0W1a1PdJDPCamYnbcnjfb0iqHJMG6lDiiLaOQlu0vNzymbbyI0z7R86Dw+OxieYYZXYsCG1INmMEMFEQIAkd6zy+xiL1yHdRDlms24IDOJ8ztIACmdonf0oVbs66VFLnThLdttIUAbksjBTqkqCxGqPehsFitiyhnHTSiddyJRzvzW/HYgIwAf/L2VgwPToriSrgSQCO9aLiIhSU2cwrp1HKk9GkEHkH+sMrTK4lQbYvyzwz9DpZY5G289/QVp8TozYZ35Kxv6bVnYsMpMvqUkEE7jTEwAfumjTZ12nU8MDAqUfgOVcotfRyLE4tjtvX1kXH2ApzjMAFcbc0U2E0rIWB+tUTS0eXSSESoyc0dg80/DpogWA/3oHtW2zlqoe3qa50hGkZWscg3IrP8AxpKBzjC7eXn0pN9lftS0CkXeR4jVVCbAIpTg8rCcU1tv0qtG+MWjD4Ioa5lSvzTLSKyU0w9I554pwotMqAbQW6foN6l8ONRJPueny9DwPnVn/EC2BctOCAdLKQV56jfuO1Q1u5DkMSeo/wCalJbLR6Q+M3VKltyI24UdFXtA/vW3DY8W3a254+6xM6ieg9hAn6dzqwx4AHTcDb/t9PX5DvW7McvW+h6FTIjsOgPQk7T600afYstDzDvIk8GNI6nbk+n770uzfA6yGA8/EjY7xttwOaS5Znzi4LV4Q/mE8Dk6QPQCBFVaNqn1ANNTiJaZPW/tSBSXZlAMyoY6WLQBI5ACih8z8Tqh8tsu/wDO4A32UQBzVbh7mkBG4Jj5E/3P50HjPDVu6xKaYA06TxuZJ/I0VJeTmn4OeDM7yOLzMzE8zwVmBt+H/mqrK84tX1mNDkqWlQUOk94P500fwirdiv5RIMflR2S+FltS7AF+oGwIHG3Smck+kCmhJgDfd9Bs2xqJGrSd5JOoFeNxMesTXSshyVMOjEBS7ctAHT7sDpPQz868y/BaY2A7AD9zTLM72i2WjgdOvpTpUrEbtkviyPildHkcgXNvKDvBI6RuQ0Ec7qRsMuJKkadS6fKQYdSFiJGwYHXIP+n0rA3tUlYJeQAeOhZD/u8sRwT/ALKXW7vCoxC7AH+XTBQMOkqSvupNY5uzVBFEmKVjpWBIMjse3eD+oo6zc0qoBO6nmpmzf1XHJja2JPUknn09Pan6khbY58tTfaHa7JjHjcsAZB60FczPYqBwKo72EDVpTKFPStPFHnvCiTXVqDQd+aMbFmINUz5SgHFBnKUHSklGxHgEVrEFzHTrR3wk7UYcsA3ArD7N6UOJ3oj0MaztsZrQjECttr1FX0aT17zA1tS9XxcViGFGjrJX+ISakttJ2kH9agcQ4ADDcrxO+5ro/jgTYEGIbuOxrnlnfYb1GWpFo7iN8sYMszG0meonj3NOrGoEqYgAE+5k/TgVG4PFC24ViQsh5O8weAPyA9ZqxwblgGkEuJI/Pn04opUK3Yl8SZM1wB0++N/361oyjxCyNovgqeJPHP8AUb/KrG3BaOAeP9wAO3fr9KGxeR276NqXczpPXpBBqsZapkpIb28OtxBHUVq+EyDY7gz8h0/M/WgPDd25h5s3w2lSArx5Y6T2qrxWFBAYfWucTlIWWWYQJ2P7mmuEfcTx19IoJVAG/T9xXyOZmeD+VInQzVlKjClGb4vWfhLzEtzwO/rWGIzEIhc7qB0O4pfklxnR7zz5ydII30dPeqt6JpbEeLvlGYEagSOIBEdR6/voKxtWi7swjzkBl33Y7hh2DDzb/wCrtXmd211MRzMgevt0ozIMG3w2uNwiwPUmTv6iT9axdm3pWD4O4Hu3UIIdQiHfkCqkqFuqBxoqM8EXDcxV7VuNob67VWyDcLTuIWukqnQqdxPXmsrTTW5l1E7Vtt2YrUuiDBnU1pFozvXt7HIH0zvW+Z4rqOMktiIrH7MtfFTWvehRx6lwEgVsdRO1KHQg7D863257H60a8i2EvbI3mvgPWtT4heCDNYJikXkCuOF/i22GwzSAYII/4rmyiB8+ldJ8Q4pLuHuKvIAOw7GueYlQpBjp+5qcuy0H7TTibIcRxHXqBWzLM7uWCRdB0qsKY/8AEH1619ZJkbDf970VdsowOoauYHVjHPoJ/SuhOtMMo3tFRlWYpcCGVgjbfr69qpLNsFlA4Ubj3muW2snuJLYdiGBELypnoQeOtVnh3xAGIVoS43lZG2Kuogc8qdt/WqKu0Rd+S+w+GUiCJB23ra+FCW2UcRIHb0FasuxQdQTsRyKJzm7ptg1TwJ5Jm9fAO5pJic5W2pLTHcbwJ5jrFGYq2XiO9D4fJ0J33EkgHp3FRVFGaMpwr4twzDSgO4H3bg6GPar27hwqaQuwHHEUJl1pUUACABtFbczxuhGI3MbDvPFO3oRLZDY868QQoGldjGoHV7ddqoc1vixgdoiDP96W5LZL3AWChiSSOPpNJf4h5yZGGX0BHv1rNjVyo05HUQr+GlvyXbsfeYxNPMvxyu7g9DQ+S2xhsFsOFk+8Uu8IrrubjZiX5+lc9ybOjqKRW3MxRdgJPatBvu/GwoLGYxEZuOaFTOGPA2rQiLC7WUw+snemttKQvjrh6GiMPiLvb60UBj74c159nFacLcY80XFGkLbJnA5lbZwBp+vFHYnNLStG1asVkCCGthQfQDj1oZMi82pjM0loJsvZxhhuYn86Fv8AiDDQIjntW/MfDCMAVml17wwpHFcpKgtMY4y9aew5QAkpvtXOswgECPXtV3lmCdLdxGBPlMetRma2xOx3/f0qcn7isF7RfbBG568daOww8w56Ex2G/wCooNB3NFW2g8fn+VIx0P8ALE8wjeRKnqTMb/nRPiDwz9oQXFBV0BgjckdPfahcCzbkQGT16QTMztyDXQMjgqEJkwKaF8kJPogf4eZje1my76ghjfkehner3MMYCpQ/I9j6+lJ87yB7N9cVh14/6iAxK9TQuMxwI1E8natEnX9meKtmXWOoj+5o+yu/50ow2KQknUO3PXateK8RW7fJkwYA3Mz/AOqkkWKxbwUfv6VM5zjvjOqr9xJII/m7VP4vHX8V5FBRJMnqR6UfgkUBVgkgRJ9O570MkqjQ0IW7KDIdQfzMNIWfu/XzVzy5bbFY97sNpVyBJnjb6VbYa4iYW477EKQDO2+3FS2Cx6khbMDqW6DvSYU0m0HM1aQ+znElMMUnzHb5Vu8IWgqkjosUjzrHq4EHUF2nuaovByEW55muUXVHckEvhbU+Yb+vWvXezbXZRR2KtqzDYzWf+FK3KirpNk9Eff8AEB16UQkT0FUmBzdCokwaYpkNv+UfSgcX4VRzI29jRoWz67nttTBavf8AHrX89BHwkk7kmPWsv/iqev1rg0yhwVwXDpXmtmJsaDpaN+KSYS46MHT50zvO93djB9KXYiD/APDvJIff2oRE71pd7ipAY1nhgY83NFIY3FRBBHpXJc4txcuDYhWMH0nv1rrUVzbxll2i+5HFyCo7H8X57/OpzQ8GTK7+5rMMQOhjj+lfMsGvk5NTKlFkNyCdSalZYPl31d49OauPDbHRAG6wCSZkg8fSK55kl46hEfP8R6b/ADq4yRyC5gnS4GmYM7SQOvJ+gqkHsSa0W963In0+RrlHiTKg7wHIUGYH6V1nCklBqG+8iue+JrYS8w6Hirzuk0Z490SF3LVUQCwG/XvWixYRIhdxO5325JnvtTvFJIoBcL1BjeP71BybLxSC8MpieshhHtEUbhQCeNztt3oa1cUEAdZA+Yo3BWCxWP8A361mmy8UB+MQfsaWUgF3knsq/wDNTOXWgi/DRSS2zMePU1X+ONQZEWPIg26SdzUtbtX7nlLKienNaseoUzNk3KzfZwqk/DXcLy3+o10zLcELdpEUdKlfDuBtl0tW99J1O36fnV0UYcU3kC6NKYMneisPZI5rWGY9a3hduadUBmYsHvWi/ZYAmYrO25HWsryFx6f0otit0CWEkatUjv39qz+Iv8rVvtn8Ecjy9q8+yP3qD5fAty+RdpArJmjimGBtIyy4E+taMaig+SIp+W6KIxRZG9eRFeI0jtWJI70xwRh7q9qkPH+FlVuDblSfzqmUHpS7xDhjcsup6CR6EUktoaLpnLGbbt2rWBW+5aIA45isFSoMujbhbpRgw5BECNxHB9BV74exS/dUwxAYlh20mPnp/OufW0ltz++eKtvCmJDKCxBOk7kcMNtvcRTRdMWatHTMFEbT5hq+tc28e4VxildAQoEvuIP/AG8zXRMvfygn0B6/vc1LeLbel2JHO4Pcdvetkn7DIl7iQW/qHbr7Vq1wOOs/3rfcQf3/ACrRccNx0NZJOjVFGxWkAx7VQeHrJZgIO28+nMVPoDIUdIq48N2tNss3PFRjHlJIpJ8YnPfEeKIxFwPMEyD2pemHtkSXcg9BNNvE9lbmJZByN57RyTWjKUHxUTUrzxArW9Izdlt4Sy5Ut6lXSW+sdKfKxneteFTQgHevFJJ3rovRz0bXFabjMOK26JrO1bNMgMywoLb6TFAeJ8UbeHYqSDwCO9O7DsFiKDzTC67TKRJNdJNxaXZOS0yLOLvWBZd2JU/enoCaqf8AHE/mP0qS8R3E0IiyzjaCflxSz/FLn8n5VmTcdWQ5tHRcPhXcSBtQjlgSD0p/gzCUlvGST61ezT0eajFe/DHJ2r4Vhc4onWYPd07LvXz3toI52rC396tq811Bs5bnNgrddeIJjaOtAAE9eKceJv8A7Nz3/pSa5ytZ2q0aE9We7zNUXhhipdekajO0entv+lILjcfKnOV/eHqpn12auGOqZG4AG8z26dv6UF43TyI3uK05HsV90/Q0f4w/+t/3D+taoO4NGWWpnN8S2nnp+poIseg3MVvx/wDWsMNzWWTNMEF4C0+saYJkAzXRrCi3a0tAIEn3NR2Ribq+9UebmFf2NdgW2wZn4Ob3b2q5iH3MK2/pNEeFsQvxFYL6UNl3/TxX+z+ponwn98e1Wl5JRXR1AINCsTzRFqyOaxTdE9qMs8U0FoEmD31CgkKSew61qRHiWYLAkqNz9aZLxQuCQGTG55PejVuiMpNE82NuFX0I8D7rE8+sVi2eOrgJ50Cecn8LdB+tUWY+VDG1SthAt3yiNQJPrUptxaSJXK+xBmV1jcLBCXY9e/pQ2jE//gfqP71pLF7l7USYbbciPaKJ+I38zf8Akf71nlkaYkuz/9k=`

You can generate this format by following [link](https://www.base64-image.de/).

This link will generate base64 with file extension. I have even saved videos, pdf, doc file by just giving their respective base64 with file extension.

Hoping that this will make your task easier.